# Looping through arguments in Shell Scripting skipping the first argument

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUPDIR=$1
for argnum in {2..$#};do
    echo ${"$argnum"}
done
```

I have tried this but it gives me this error:
./backup.sh: 10: ./backup.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; variables you define yourself should have at least one lower-case character in their names. See paragraph 4 of the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: (Also, you can't use variables in a brace expansion such as `{2..$#}` -- see [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D)).

Comment: ...actually, brace expansion for numeric ranges isn't guaranteed to work with `/bin/sh` *at all*, even with constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `shift` command to remove `$1` from the argument list after you're done reading it (thus renumbering your old `$2` to `$1`, your old `$3` to `$2`, etc):

```
#!/bin/sh
backupdir=$1; shift
for arg; do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

To provide a literal (but not-particularly-good-practice) equivalent to the code in the question, indirect expansion (absent such [security-impacting practices as `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^-- This IS NOT GUARANTEED TO WORK in /bin/sh

# not idiomatic, not portable to baseline POSIX shells; this is best avoided
backupdir=$1
for ((argnum=2; argnum<=$#; ++argnum)); do
  echo "${!argnum}"
done
```